# Why does the volume of the preamplifier change when a second audio signal is mixed?

Tags: amplifier, audio, signal, impedance

I have two audio signals leading to the amplifier input: the first one comes from the preamplifier, the second one from the audio output of a smartphone/tablet device. Both have a resistor and a capacitor in series for DC blocking as shown below:
[image: Mixer]

When the MP3 input from the smartphone is not connected, or when the player is paused, the preamplifier works correctly. However, when MP3 playback is started, the volume of the preamp is attenuated, then returns to the original level after about 5/10 seconds when the MP3 playback is paused. As a result, there is an instant jump in the preamp volume, which is approximately half of the initial volume to the ear. The 5-second delay should be due to the smartphone amplifier going into powerdown.

What is causing this phenomenon and how can I correct it? Are the impedances not balanced correctly? I found a decent balance with R38 10Ω and R39 470Ω, but it doesn't sound good, some brightness of the sound is lost, and there is definitely a more correct approach to balancing the signals.

Does this phenomenon have a common name? I would like to better understand why this happens, but not knowing what to look for, I couldn't even do research.
Thank you.

RIN+ input impedance 20K
Maximum output current of Preamp 50mA

Comment: Imagine connecting MP3 to GND.  That would halve your signal if R38 = R39.   The output impedance of your MP3 device is very low would be my guess.    Do you actually want to mix the signals together or do you only ever use one side or the other at a time?

Comment: If you "merged" two voltages (A and B) with same value resistors you would get the arithmetical mean and not A+B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add two signals "properly", it is not enough to simply connect them with resistors. One should use an op-amp adder circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f10V2m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The secret of this circuit is that the inverting input of the op-amp is at "virtual ground". So each input only "sees" a resistor to ground. Each input is "invisible" to the other input. What happens at one, will not affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

You are short circuiting two outputs together. Or rather, mixing them with resistors.

If they both have 100 ohm output impedance, the output from each device is halved because the output amplifier is driving a 100 ohm load through 100 ohm source impedance.

Whem phone output is paused, the output amplifier is disabled and then the other amplifier can drive the input directly instead of there being an extra load from the output impedance.